# If $G \leq \text{Aut}(E)$ and $G$ is finite, where $E$ is a field, is it true that $|G| = [E: \text{Fix}(G)]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I also know that $ [E: \text{Fix}(G)] < \infty $. (This is a piece of a problem.) If we let $G$ act on a set of basis vectors of $E$ over $\text{Fix}(G)$, can we use the Orbit-Stabilizer theorem to conclude this somehow?

Comment: See this question: [Is every subgroup of automorphisms a Galois group?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602669/is-every-subgroup-of-automorphisms-a-galois-group).

Comment: Generally there will not be a basis on which $G$ acts.